# jQuery: how to change background image by typing in a text field?

Tags: jquery, image, input, background, transition

What I want to do is make a web page that changes its background image in response to a user-entered string. If the string matches one, it will change the initial image to the corresponding image. However, **this only works for *certain strings***. In other words, you won't get a flower image just because you entered `flower`. If the string does not match with the code, nothing happens.

I'm sure that there's some way to do it with a `switch` statement, though I'm not certain *how*.

Comment: Following Ben's and sany2k8's answers, I came up with this as a test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/xHbK5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
$(function() {
  var $backgroundElm = $("#bkelm");
  $("#inputelm").on("keyup", function () {
    console.log("working..." + $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() === 'flower') {
        $backgroundElm.css("background-image", "url(http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiCAV98SUrpkGrWgUXvJ8dZYzZQmxyBVMr2v9cDJoyy2grjrDw)");
    } else if ($(this).val() === "yellow") {
        $backgroundElm.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

and heres the [live example](http://jsbin.com/liraqu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I was hoping that the change would occur when I hit Enter/Return, not immediately.

Comment: Change 'keyup' to 'change'

Comment: if you want a button to do this just add a button and bind to the click event there. Let me know if you need help doing that. It's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way mate

```
$('#target').keyup(function(event){

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){

        //do you backgroud change functionality here
        if ($(this).val() === 'a'){
          //do something
        } 
        else if ($(this).val() === "b") {
        //do something else
        }
    }
});
```